# "This iPhone cannot be backed up because there is not enough iCloud storage available." but more than 2TB are available

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos.app

This is weird and annoying: I'm getting "This iPhone cannot be backed up because there is not enough iCloud storage available." when I have more than 2TB free in iCloud. See screenshots below.

I have shot 280 GB of long videos recently, and they are also stuck with iCloud Photo Library saying "Syncing 45 items to iCloud" after days of being plugged in almost all the time with the screen off most of the time.

I have the 2TB iCloud plan + Apple One. I have gone over 2TB in the past, so I don't understand why this iPhone in particular stopped backing up now. Other devices seem to still be able to get backed up and sync photos and videos.

Anyone experienced anything similar?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]